# Friends reunited?

Tags: expressions, translation

I used to see my Phd Supervisor regularly every fortnight. I have not seen him for a while after my graduation. I would like now to drop him a line to say I would like to... (suggest an expression): 
 - 1)renew our meeting?
 - 2) revive our meeting? 
 - 3) renew seeing each other... 
 - 4...?

We have an equivalent expression to indicate what was said above. It's a bit literary though. I wonder if there is such an expression in English.

Comment: What is the expression in your native language? That will help immensely if there is a related idiom in English. Also, you need to be more explicit (give more details) about the expression. 'meeting' and 'renew' is not enough/

Comment: I have heard people using "reconnect". It doesn't mean specifically to re-establish the former fortnightly meeting habit, but just to get in touch with him again.

Answer (score 1):

‘I would like us to return to meeting regularly’ *or* ‘I would like to return to meeting you regularly’.

Though I certainly prefer the first.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you could say is 'I would like start meeting with you again sometime.' (you can exclude the 'sometime' if that sounds better to you.)
If you want to use one of your options, I would choose the first one.